# How to start Login screen which is in MVC 5 Areas by default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I just like to have login screen by default which is located at MVC 5 Areas some area X.

I will share my code please review it

My RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "X/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Y", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
  namespaces: new[] { "Areas.Controllers" }
);
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return RedirectToAction("Login", "Y", new { area = "X" });
}
```

My Root Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/X/Y/Index" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>
```

My Area Register:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
          "A",
          "X/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { action = "Index", controller = "User", id = 
                    UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

My Question is to get login screen but i am not getting the screen.... Only when I check the output from the login view is fine but the remaining cases it doesn't works properly. Please help me

Comment: Have you registered the area using `RegisterAllAreas`? Are you sure if `Index` method redirects properly to the area (check with browser's network tab)?

Comment: I registerd all the areas in Global.asax.....

Comment: I am getting 404 error.... Saying Returnurl to Account/Login but Account /Login is not present

Comment: and also i am getting the error 
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it straight then your root/home controller is Y based on your example, and your Login action is based on your User controller in area X.

Assuming this is correct then  `RouteConfig.cs` should look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Y", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Controller Y in The `Controllers` folder should look like this:

```
public class Y : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         return RedirectToAction("Login", "User", new { area = "X" });
    }
}
```

Your area registration like this:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "X_Default",
        "X/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller="User", action = "Login", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Config like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/X/User/Login" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>
```

And in your Areas/X/Controllers folder

```
public class User : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
         // do your login stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: When i giving routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Security_Default1",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: It takes directly to the account/login but account/login is not present in my project